# Is Ubuntu mostly written in C#?

Tags: programming, language-support, c#

On Ohloh, Ubuntu is reported as "[mostly written in C#](https://web.archive.org/web/20130120093811/https://www.ohloh.net/p/ubuntu)", and, indeed, if we go to the [Ubuntu's languages summary](https://web.archive.org/web/20130814121300/https://www.ohloh.net/p/ubuntu/analyses/latest/languages_summary) we see that C# has the most LOCs, accounting for approximately 20% of the code base.

If the Ohloh's engine isn't wrong, what is the explanation of this?

Comment: The explanations is... they chose to write a lot of the applications in the project in C#, I fail to see how this needs answering.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**The Oloh engine is  way wrong**. Ubuntu is a quite complex project, and it's difficult to state what is Ubuntu and what is not. But C# is not by any measure the most popular language.

Ubuntu has also much more than 50 contributors and 1500 commits/year even if you only count Ubuntu specific patches.

This site seems to [follow](http://www.ohloh.net/p/ubuntu/enlistments?page=2) some strange mix of Ubuntu and non-Ubuntu projects, it doesn't make sense. It's likely than F-Spot (a big program that is not in the default install base now and it's made in C#) is weighting heavy on that statistic.

Answer (score 6):

The Linux Kernel (which is the core of Ubuntu) is written mostly in C and a little parts in assembly languages. And many of the applications are written in python or C or C++. C# is not a popular language for many linux users/developers because it was meant to be used for Windows. But still you are free to use it. Its just that people mostly give preference to languages other than C#.
   I have seen the source code of Linux kernel and I can be 100% sure that 99% is C. You can also download the source code from the official site of linux kernel. The site is http://www.kernel.org . There you will mostly see "*.h" which are referred to as "Header" files and "*.c" which are "C Programming" files.

So the article you are reading is wrong. And by wrong I mean dead wrong. Please notify the site's admin for the changes also.

Comment: Downvote: While this is true, you don't give any references and links, so this answer is just an opinion and it's not useful for this site purpose.

Comment: @JavierRivera I have added some references and links. And this is not an opinion, its a true fact. Download and extract the source code to see.

Comment: @PranitBauva OP was referring to Ubuntu, as in all the applications in the Ubuntu project including unity etc. not the linux kernel.

Comment: @JavierRivera Thanks to you! To prove my point I read some books on C Programming so that I could understand the language of the source kernel and then I could prove my point.!

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu is definetely NOT written in C#! Ubuntu does not even (as far as i know) ship with any C# / Mono applications installed although they are available in software centre (banshee etc)

Ubuntu like most distros is made up of alot of C and C++, mix in some vala, python, perl and many others. C# is a bit of a sore point due to MS/.net connections.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu is a distribution containing a *lot* of individual projects each of which are free to use whatever language they want to implement their project.

C++ is a quite frequent choice for programmers who need the C ecosystem but want a bit more from the language.